# WaitForChanged in a loop not firing after first call

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

Cheers! I am working with .net 4.0 and writing a vb.net console application. The application has to monitor a folder and do something every time a new file is saved into it

It always works the first go around, but subseqent go-rounds seem to fail, and i can not figure out why. To test it i have a bunch of test images in a test folder that i copy over 1 at a time to the capture folder, wait for it process, and then try to drop another one in there.

The code is as follows:

```
Public Sub FileChanges()
      Dim result As System.IO.WaitForChangedResult
      watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
      watchfolder.Path = My.Settings.WATCHDIR.ToString()
      Console.WriteLine("Application Running, Waiting for a file")
      result = watchfolder.WaitForChanged(System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
      Console.WriteLine("Filechange Detected")
      Dim fileName As String = My.Settings.WATCHDIR.ToString() & result.Name.ToString()
End Sub
sub main()
   Do
     system.threading.thread.sleep(5000)
     FileChanges()
   Loop
End Sub
```

Any thoughts? Any better way in a console application to wait until a file is created and then do something?

Comment: Use a single FileSystemWatcher, don't create one over and over again.  And don't sleep for 5 seconds, that's pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the watcher only once, and enable raising events:

```
watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

Then use a handler to handle the change event:

```
Private Sub watchfolder_event(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As system.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles watchfolder.changed
...
```

Here's an example that works in VB 2008:

```
Module Module1

Dim WithEvents watchfolder As New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

Sub Main()
watchfolder.Path = "c:\tmp"
watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True

For i As Integer = 1 To 500
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
  Console.WriteLine("tick " & i)
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub watchfolder_event(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles watchfolder.Changed
Console.WriteLine("changed.")
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The issue i ran into with adding a handler is that under a console application the application would just exit as the file handler is attaching to a different thread, and i am unsure how to synchronize it in a console application.

Comment: Make sure you declare watchfolder at the module level. I've added a sample console app that works (vs 2008).

Comment: I modified the code as you listed above, however watchfolder.changes is not getting hit...

Comment: Make sure you've got "watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True" after initializing watchfolder, and double check the folder name.